# Pygame on to ESP8266

Tags: python, arduino, pygame, esp8266, micropython

Is it possible to load external python libraries onto a microprocessor and get it to work with micropython? How would I approach this problem? I have an esp8266, and am worried that it does not have enough flash space for the large library, but I believe that can be remedied with an additional flash chip connected over SPI

Answer (score 1):

I think its not possible at all because Pygame relies on underlying layers of the operating system which the MicroPython interpreter does not have.

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible, its not about the flash size,
Pygame use the userinterface to make animations ect,
in order to do that with ESP or any other microcontroller/boards you need to use : [OLED](https://www.amazon.fr/Display-Serial-Module-Resolution-Arduino/dp/B07BV9FFF9) or [TFT screen](https://www.amazon.fr/LLAni-UART-%C3%89cran-tactile-Arduino/dp/B07R1W887C), witch has a libraries that help you to implement something like Pygame.
but runing the same Pygame library will not work as @[Lukas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10797372/lukas) has expalined